# How to format a Python list in a for and if loop?

Tags: python

I am creating a five number summary python program, which incorporates the CSV module to view the file. I am having issues viewing the CSV file in python. When python reads the file at the front of the first comma separated value is some weird characters, how would I delete these weird characters so I can just have the number, which I can use in a list?
Here is my code:

```
import csv

fileName = "numraw.csv" 
firstNumList = [] # This is a "working" list
endNumList = [] # This is the list that summaries will be made on
tstlst = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'] 
elementL = []
elementL2 = []
with open(fileName, newline="") as csvfile:
    read5sum = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for element in read5sum:
        prtllst = str(element)
prtllst = list(prtllst.split(',')) 
for element in prtllst: 
    elementL = list(element.split(","))
    for element2 in elementL: 
        for element3 in element2:
            if element3 in tstlst:
                element3 = int(element3)
                print(element3)
            list(firstNumList).append(element3)
            firstNumList = "[]".join(firstNumList)
            print(firstNumList)
```

Sorry if its a dumb question, I am learning the CSV Module. 
The for loop which is being used is me trying to solve it.
All help would be appreciated

EDIT: Here is the csv files context: 
56,5,1,84,32,69,23,35
EDIT#2: Here is the csv output in python:
["['ï»¿56", '5', '1', '84', '32', '69', '23', "35']"]

Comment: Can you and an example input and example output for this to make it easier?

Comment: `split()` gives list - you don't have to use `list()`

Comment: `firstNumList` is a list - you don't need to use `list()` - you can do `firstNumList.append(element3)` without `list()`

Comment: Put the content of the csv file here pastebin.com and past its link here.

Comment: if you have list - ie. `data` - and you don't need first element then you can slice it `data = data[1:]`

Comment: I don't see `weird characters` in your context. Is it directly before `56` ? How it looks like when you `print()` data from file ?

Comment: Can you provide the row with unwanted characters of the CSV file with Header?

Comment: @furas that is correct

Comment: maybe it is [BOM - Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). If `decode()` in anwser will not work then you can still read it as string and slice `text[3:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing seems to be because of encoding. Can you update the `open` function to add an encoding and also open it in binary? You code should look something like this.

```
with open("filename.txt", "rb") as f:
    contents = f.read().decode("UTF-8")
```